# String of Bytes to Byte array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, hex, byte

Im trying to make function that takes this pattern string :

```
"07 C5 8F E1 FD CA 8C E2 D4 FD BC E5 03 C6 8F E2"
```

to return this BYTE array

```
BYTE pattern[] = { 0x07, 0xC5, 0x8F, 0xE1, 0xFD, 0xCA, 0x8C, 0xE2, 0xD4, 0xFD, 0xBC, 0xE5, 0x03,  0xC6, 0x8F, 0xE2};
```

What i tried:

```
BYTE strPatternToByte(std::string pattern, int len)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream(pattern);
    while(std::getline(tokenStream, token, ' '))
    {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    BYTE somePtr[len];
    for ( int i=0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        somePtr[i] = '0x' +  tokens[i];
    }

    return somePtr;
}
```

but the line to convert to pattern of bytes didn't work for me,

```
somePtr[i] = (byte) tokens[i];
```

is there a way in c++ to automatically parse them into bytes or something like in java?

Comment: Another problem in your source: you are returning a pointer to a local variable, which is undefined behavior. Also, you are using non-standard extension of C++ - variable-length array.

Comment: i have noticed, so what you are suggesting to return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `(byte) tokens[i]` doesn't translate a string to another type, instead it asks the compiler to treat the `std::string` object in `tokens[i]` as a `byte`, which it isn't and can't be converted to. It's basically you telling a lie to the compiler. In fact, basically all C-type casting should be a red flag that you're doing something wrong.

One solution is to instead use the normal stream extraction operator `>>` to parse each space-delimited hexadecimal sequence as an unsigned integer:

```
std::vector<unsigned> values;
std::istringstream stream(pattern);

unsigned value;
while (stream >> std::hex >> value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}
```

Comment: This solved some of the errors, but not my main problem , it still doesn' t return as i want
for some reasons..

Comment: @J.Steve As mentioned in another comment, the code you show returns a pointer to a local variable. ***But*** converted to `BYTE`. Use vectors, return the vector.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why this doesn't work if I change `unsigned` to `uint8_t`